# Where are `Malformed and `Uchar defined?

Tags: ocaml

NB: This question is more about how to navigate through/decipher OCaml source code, than about the specifics of the items listed below.<sup>1</sup>

I've come across the expressions

```
`Malformed
`Uchar
```

in some OCaml source code, but I can't find definitions for them.

Are they somehow built-in, i.e. part of the standard language?

If not, where does one go when one wants to find out such definitions?  (Actually, it's not clear to me whether the leading backtick is part of the name or is a separate operator.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm having a horrible time making sense of OCaml source code.  Usually I have no problem picking up new programming languages, but with OCaml I can't find anything where I expect to find it, and when I do find something it comes along with 100x more undefined/differently-defined/outright bizarre names/concepts, so it's a losing battle.</sup>

Comment: OCaml is from a different family of languages than the usual, which is one reason it's worth learning. Mainstream languages draw from a fairly small pool of ideas. (If you're familiar with FP languages, logic languages, etc., please forgive the comment.)

Comment: Might I suggest learning from [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a polymorphic variant, you can read about it in the OCaml manual [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html#sec46)

For other basic language features you would not understand, well, you should first read the whole part 1 of the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/index.html)

Here is how the manual is organized:

1. Quick introduction through the language
2. The whole language (two parts: first the legacy language, then the features added through time)
3. The standards shell tools manpages (compilers, interprets, ocamlbuild etc.)
4. The standard libraries

I noted from your previous questions that you use non-standard tools, such as opam and several libraries, make sure to check their documentations and note that some can extend your syntax.

I have to admit that the doc generally assumes people reading it already know about the concepts presented but you don't need to use them at first to master the language.

Happy hacking !

Answer (score 2):

It is a polymorhic variant, that do bot need to be defined before usage. It is something between lisp's symbols and common ADT's. You think of it as a syntactically lighter version version of common ADTs.

I would suggest you to use `utop` as a playing ground to learn OCaml. Indeed, it is a damn easy language, it looks like to me that you have atacked it from a wrong side, or working with a program that is obfuscated.